# Apply LibreOffice sum to multiple renamed sheets

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with many sheets, each tracking a particular topic.  Within each sheet are columns of raw data, and a cell (always in F1) that contains a calculated stat for the raw data.

I will be adding new sheets with some regularity.

I would like to have a "Summary" sheet as well, which will, say, `SUM` that stat in F1 from every other sheet.  I know I can manually specify the sheets like

```
SUM(FirstSheetName.F1;AnotherName.F1;...)
```

but that will require manual maintenance of that field each time a new sheet is added, which I assume I'll forget to do.  Is there a way to specify a formula to apply, say, a glob or something like that, to the sheet names, so I could do something more like `SUM(*.F1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using two small macros (to determine the name of the last sheet) in combination with the range operator and the **[`INDIRECT()`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT)** function.

First, create the following macro (`Tools` -> `Macros` -> `LibreOffice Basic`, create a new module or use the default module; paste the following code):

```vb
Function LastSheetName()
    Dim nSheetCount As Integer
    nSheetCount = ThisComponent.getSheets().Count
    LastSheetName = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByIndex(nSheetCount - 1).getName()
End Function

Function LastSheetCell(sCell)
    LastSheetCell = LastSheetName() & "." & sCell ' notice: sheet/cell separator may be "!"
End Function
```

*Notice: depending on you localization settings, you may have to replace the dot `.` in the `LastSheetCell()` function by an exclamation mark:*

```vb
LastSheetCell = LastSheetName() & "!" & sCell
```

With this macro defined, you can this user-defined functions in you sheet:

```vb
=LASTSHEETNAME()               ' returns e.g. "Sheet10" as String
=LASTSHEETCELL("F1")           ' returns e.g. "Sheet10.F1" as String
=INDIRECT(LASTSHEETCELL("F1")) ' returns a cell reference to "Sheet10.F1"
```

Now, you've got all the components required to build the final formula:

```vb
=SUM(FirstSheetName.F1:INDIRECT(LASTSHEETCELL("F1"))) ' returns the sum of FirstSheetName.F1; ...; LastSheetName.F1
```

Notice the `:` between `FirstSheetName.F1` and the formula that creates the reference to the last sheet's cell: that's the ***[range operator](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Creating_formulas#Range_operator)***. You can use it to reference a range of sheets, too. From the OOo Calc docs:

> **Sheet1.A3:Sheet3.D4**: Reference to a cuboid range with 24 cells, 4 column width × 2 row height × 3 sheets depth.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing that all for me, works like a champ!

Comment: Nice one!  I had not heard of this type of range before.